# Apache ReWrite with SSL IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite

my conditions work in most cases redirecting to my secure site at `https://mysite.example.com`, except the user enters `https://10.10.10.10` in which case a certificate error happens, which is fine and expected. But if the user decides to proceed , I would like to redirect to my secure site.  Is this possible. See below my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.10\.10\.10$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `https://mysite.example.com`/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Yes, it is posible. Your sample seems to be good

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure `%{HTTP_HOST}` can be used to test an IP (Apache might consider there's no host per say if the host is an IP), and assuming you tested the rule from your question and it didn't work, there's definitely room for improvement.

Your SSL certificate is associated with one hostname only (unless you have a wildcard cert, but that would be an edge case), so it doesn't really matter to know if your website was access via its IP or another domain alias; all that matters if you want it to be redirected to https and a specific hostname.

By the way, if you IP change, you would have to change it both in the DNS and your rewrite rules, that's not ideal.

So let's simplify it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note that you need to hardcode `mysite.example.com` in the destination too, as it might be the IP or the wrong host, if the second condition is met.

Comment: Thank you Capsule. Your code is certainly an improvement. But it still not working with   [link](https://10.10.10.10) . I get certificate error as expected and If I decides to proceed, it goes to  [link](https://10.10.10.10) (with invalid certificate) and not [link](https://mysite.example.com)

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? Because going to the IP would definitely match `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.example.com$`

Comment: Tried several machines, several browsers, https://<IP sddress> doesn't redirect when I click proceed.. Yes, cache was cleared. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Well, if I use your code in the <Location> Directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location), it works as expected. Unfortunately, it breaks the an AJAX portion of the site...

Comment: It breaks your AJAX because you of cross-origin issues or mix of http/https? If it requests stuff from the same domain, then you should just use a relative path with no protocol or domain